# Click noise in ALSA playback

Tags: audio, alsa

I have configured ALSA for 44.1 KHZ . The alsa framework is used to capture data from the analog input using "snd_pcm_readi" api. But in our application we find that there is a click noise in the background for playback. The click noise is available in the playback even when there is no analog input, this ensures that there is no buffering issue.But we were not able to get the cause for the click noise.

Comment: Looks like question for http://superuser.com/

Comment: Are there clicks when you use `arecord`/`aplay`?

Comment: The click noise is in analog capture using the "snd_pcm_readi" . Iam not able to add the attachment.